# Is it possible to make zip files in corona?

Tags: lua, compression, zip, coronasdk

I need to send files to server, though the file size is approx. 4-5 MB but file numbers are around 40-50.

So can we make compressed folder in lua and send it to server?

I am able to extract the zip file coming through server using following link:
http://www.keplerproject.org/luazip/examples.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this page http://lua-users.org/wiki/CompressionAndArchiving which has some compression library in lua.

Comment: The question relates to Corona not plain Lua.  The latest version of Corona provides a plugin that enables ZIP file handling in Corona apps.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have the Enterprise edition of Corona and can add ZIP support yourself there's currently no way to create a ZIP file in Corona SDK.

Comment: If not .zip, is there any other way to compress a particular directory in corona SDK?